# Validating column in sql server based on length and format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to apply validation in sql server to one of my column to display only those records which are of length 3 and are of the format LetterNumberletter i.e. for e.g A2B.

Comment: Are you trying to filter what is being read from the database? Or are you trying to restrict what goes into the database in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

In the `WHERE` condition you have to find the length having 3 and `LIKE` for the pattern.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
WHERE LEN(your_column) = 3 
AND your_column LIKE '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]';
```

### <kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24d07/1)</kbd>